# Flatten lists of variable depths in Python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a list of n lists. Each internal list contains a combination of (a) strings, (b) the empty list, or (c) a list containing one string. I would like to transform the inside lists so they only contain the strings.

I have a list like this for example:

```
[[[],["a"],"a"],[["ab"],[],"abc"]]
```

and I would like it to be like this:

```
[["","a","a"],["ab","","abc"]]
```

I know I could probably go through with a loop but I am looking for a more elegant solution, preferably with a list comprehension.

Comment: Whats the maximum depth (is recursion required)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via list comprehension:

```
lst = [[[],["a"],"a"],[["ab"],[],"abc"]]
result = [ ['' if not v else (v[0] if isinstance(v, list) else v) for v in sub_l] 
           for sub_l in lst ]

print(result)
```

The output:

```
[['', 'a', 'a'], ['ab', '', 'abc']]
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, but it is very human unreadable! (not your fault Roman!)

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension:

```
>>> original = [[[],["a"],"a"],[["ab"],[],"abc"]]
>>> result = [['' if not item else ''.join(item) for item in sublist] for sublist in original]
>>> result
[['', 'a', 'a'], ['ab', '', 'abc']]
```

Answer (score 1):

As every element of the list that you'd like to flatten is iterable, instead of checking of being instance of some class (list, string) you can actually make use of duck-typing:

```
>> my_list = [[[],["a"],"a"],[["ab"],[],"abc"]]
>> [list(map(lambda x: ''.join(x), elem)) for elem in my_list]
```

Or more readable version:

```
result = []
for elem in my_list:
    flatten = map(lambda x: ''.join(x), elem)
    result.append(list(flatten))
```

Result:

```
[['', 'a', 'a'], ['ab', '', 'abc']]
```

It's quite pythonic to not to check **what** something is but rather leverage transformation mechanics to adaptive abilities of each of the structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
 original_list = [[[],["a"],"a"],[["ab"],[],"abc"]]
 flatten = lambda x: "" if x == [] else x[0] if isinstance(x, list) else x
 flattened_list = [[flatten(i) for i in j] for j in original_list]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.